# Ennforcing mutually exclusive install on Windows?

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer, installshield

We have Product A and Product A'.  They're nearly identical and easily confused.  For legal reasons, it is necessary to keep these subtly different.  For technical reasons, it is not possible for the two to co-exist and run correctly.  Therefore, we want to prevent the user from installing Product A if Product A' is already installed, and vice versa.

**Is there a best practice for enforcing this on Windows?**

My initial thought is to use a different upgrade code for Product A and A' and use this to clue in that the other is installed, but I'm sure there are other approaches and/or best practices.

Comment: I would go with the upgrade code check. Add a check similar to the one to prevent downgrades (but different version bounds). For extra future-safety, implement it for a handful of predetermined upgrade codes (in case you need to change the upgrade code in the future and still maintain mutual exclusivity).

Comment: That's an awesome suggestion @MichaelUrman.  Under what conditions might the Upgrade Code change?  I thought that remained the same for the lifetime of a product?

Comment: It typically does remain unchanged, except if you have to merge or split products. Or if you have to change your side-by-side rules, you may have to change it. But why exactly would these scenarios come up? I'm not sure. Business decisions, probably. So adding extra ones is probably a case of over-engineering, albeit a cheap one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the Windows Installer package developer is able do this without resorting to custom actions by [Using Properties in Conditional Statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aee818aa-912d-4e59-b061-61cd35993593).

The [LaunchConditions action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa369751) queries the [LaunchCondition table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa369752) and evaluates each conditional statement recorded there. If any of these conditional statements fail, an error message is displayed to the user and the installation is terminated.

The LaunchConditions action is normally the first in the sequence, but the [AppSearch Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa367578%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be sequenced before the LaunchConditions action.

The AppSearch action uses file signatures to search for existing versions of products. The AppSearch action can also be used to set a property to the existing value of an registry or .ini file entry.

The first time the Installer finds the file signature at a suggested location, it stops searching for this file or directory, and sets the corresponding property in the [AppSearch Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/Windows/Desktop/aa367579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That property can then be evaluated using [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/6f1657f9-063b-4d57-ad76-95e3dbe25786) in the LaunchCondition table.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRovetta I hadn't considered this option yet.  It sounds like I could use the Component Id in the other package as a signature, re-schedule AppSearch, and then use Standard Launch conditions

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom action to enumerate through the list of installed products.

```
//using using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

IEnumerable<ProductInstallation> installedProducts = ProductInstallation.GetProducts(null, null, Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.UserContexts.Machine);
foreach (ProductInstallation installedProduct in installedProducts)
    {
        if (installedProduct.ProductName == "Name of Product A'")
        {
            // set some property in your installer to indicate the product can't be installed
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't do before, but a solution is to storing a key-value on Windows registry when installing (first time) the product A (or A').

Every time, the installer of A (or A') runs, it checks if that key exists, if true abort the installation, else continue with installation. 
Remember if the user uninstall the product, then remove the key in the registry too.

For more info about Windows registry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry

For information about add, edit, delete keys: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516

Comment: +1 I like this because people not familiar with Upgrade Codes will understand setting a flag in the registry